# What is the point in the doctype declaration at the top of html form? Does it change anything?

Tags: html, xhtml

Been writing web apps for years and this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Has always confused me. What is it for exactly? What are the implications if I remove it?

I understand the w3c conventions about nested elements etc but what actually happens why is the declaration there do browsers fail or something if I take it out?

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It kicks the browser into standards mode, which makes the browser properly render elements. Not every doctype kicks the browser into standards mode, see [this chart](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/). If a valid doctype is not used to kick the browser into standards mode, the browser will basically try to render your page according to "standards" ( or lack thereof ) in 2002-2003 when everyone used crappy table layouts. You **do not** want quirks mode.

**Conclusion**: always use a doctype.

Answer (score 0):

The doctype declaration tells the browser how it should interpret the HTML contents that follow. There's a good overview of how and why in the introduction to Mark Pilgrim's book [Dive Into HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html#the-doctype)

Answer (score 0):

It iforms the browser of what elements will be used, and affects the rendering of the page. (Mostly IE)

In many cases, elements will not always display correctly if a DOCTYPE is left out.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 2.0, 3.2, 4.x and XHTML 1.x:

In theory:

- It allows the user agent to decode entities (e.g. `&hellip;` to …)
- It allows a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to determine which tags, attributes and attribute values are allowed where

In practice:

- It allows a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to determine which tags, attributes and attribute values are allowed where
- It allows browsers to make a guess as to if the author has a clue about what they are doing and switch between [standards mode and quirks mode](http://gutfeldt.ch/matthias/articles/doctypeswitch.html)

In HTML 5:

- It is a mystic string used to start a document so that standards mode is triggered